# Using ruamel.yaml to dump a dict of dict but ansible is complaining - turns out was about some other missing param

Tags: python, ansible-inventory, ruamel.yaml

Totally messed this up, I blame working while sick with covid. I read the "none" as relating to the inventory file but it was some other missing parameter. the python was good which was why everyone on this question including me so confused.

I'm doing the below to pull some information from a db and create an ansible inventory file:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

outfile = Path('db.yaml')

db = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

db['greenhouse1']['fruits'].append('apples')  
db['greenhouse1']['fruits'].append('oranges')
db['greenhouse1']['colors'] = ["red", "orange"]

db['greenhouse2']['fruits'].append('banana')


def default_dict_to_yaml(representer, data):
    return representer.represent_dict(dict(data.items()))

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.Representer.add_representer(defaultdict, default_dict_to_yaml)

yaml.dump(db, outfile)
```

This outputs:

```yaml
greenhouse1:
  fruits:
  - apples
  - oranges
  colors:
  - red
  - orange
greenhouse2:
  fruits:
  - banana
```

ansible complains:

```
    An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
fatal: [greenhouse1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}

inventory:
  hosts:
    greenhouse1:
      fruits:
      - apple
      - orange
      colors:
      - red
      - orange
```

For the commentor that needs to see what result yaml looks like. Playbook doesn't matter this is inventory. same error running ping action.

```
 ansible-playbook -i greenhouses.yml roleTest.yml
```

the ansible command. nothing special. It's a role that has been run many many other times it barfs only on this file when made this way.

What's going on? I used std.out, everything about the file looks fine and ansible doesn't reject the yaml. Is here something else i have to do to get this to be type string?

This works with same formatting of file if it is saved in a text editor. It's a problem with the sys.stdout. This is easily reproducible with this code and

```
ansible all -m win_ping -i greenhouses.yml
```

I will add that originally I was using yaml library but because I needed dict of dict I was directed to switch to ruamel.

Comment: Since your error is at Ansible level, the code generating the YAML in Python is irrelevant to the question. Show us the generated YAML and the task/playbook using it, rather.

Comment: it's far from irrelevant since that is the source of the problem

Comment: I have to imagine it would help to see where/how you're using it in Ansible, at least... We don't have any context for that error message.

Comment: What is that (unformatted) YAML you just added? It's not the same as what the code you've shown generates. (I edited the output YAML into the post shortly before your edit.)

Comment: _For the commentor that needs to see what result yaml looks like. Playbook doesn't matter this is inventory. same error running ping action._ > Then show us how you are using it, your error might be in the definition of the usage of a dynamic inventory, in the call to the Ansible command, in the structure of the generated inventory that Ansible needs to query. If you wan someone to help you, you should be able to come with a [mre]

Comment: that's at the very beginning fatal connecting in gtefacts. I have run this playbook before on yaml inventories

Comment: We can't really help you debug what happened without a definite set of steps that reproduce the problem. You get as far as generating the YAML and then don't explain in your question what you *do* with it that generates that error. Also... if the same playbook works fine on other YAML inventories, an example of one that *works* would almost certainly be a useful data point. (Also you haven't addressed what that *other* YAML is that you added.)

Comment: The working yaml looks exactly the same. Obviously i am changing all the names for purpose of example. Should I recopy the example of non-working and call it working? would that help you understand that the error is complaining about encoding of the file?

Comment: Huh! Well now we might be getting somewhere. So Ansible complains about the YAML file you generate in Python, but if you manually copy and paste the contents of that file into a new file and save it, that one works?

Comment: I have been saying this from the beginning. As I keep saying the code is the important thing. Everyone is focused on the piece that is actually working without any issue.  The error message says expects type str but getting Non Type

Comment: My apologies, but if you meant to communicate that, I couldn't tell. You did say that it worked with other YAML files, but how were we to know those other YAML files were visually indistinguishable? And I don't really see how that error message is supposed to indicate a file encoding issue. If it does, then it's a rather misleading error. Another question though: what exactly do you mean by "It's a problem with the `sys.stdout`"? Where do you use `sys.stdout`? That's just the stream by which things are normally printed to the screen. You're saving this to a file, correct?

Comment: I've done the dump using a pathlib object. My understanding is that is what it does? I also did sys.stdou then > filename.yml with same result

Comment: The error was: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
is the error.  This was the origin of my question. Doesn't seem like people bother reading the descriptions or question

Comment: We're spending our free time trying to help, and I can only speak for myself, but I certainly read the question, description, and error message... `pathlib` has no direct connection to `stdout`. `pathlib` is just a mechanism for interacting with the file system. `stdout` is the standard output stream. Dumping to`stdout` normally just prints to screen; redirecting your script's output with `>` would then send that to a file.

Comment: That error message usually comes from something that expects a path to a file; it wants either a string or bytes object representing the file path, or a `Path` object of the same. You can get the same error from simply `open(None)`. We don't know what code, where, is generating that error, and we don't know how it received `None` instead of the (probably file path) it needed.

Comment: well the redirect and the pathlib are both not working.

Comment: For now, what I tell is that you are outputting to `db.yaml` and using an unrelated `greenhouses.yml` files as inventory.

Comment: _I have been saying this from the beginning. As I keep saying the code is the important thing. Everyone is focused on the piece that is actually working without any issue._ > then that's the opposite of my earlier statement, tagging the question with [tag:ansible] was the irrelevant part, and you should have given, in your question, the resulting YAML and the desired YAML, leaving Ansible, totally off the question.

Comment: well ansible does seem to have something to do with it in the fact that a correctly formatted file is not enough. The encoding of the file or something is the issue

Comment: Here's one troubleshooting idea to try, that might narrow down what's happening. Start with a YAML file that works. Use a Python script to open it, read the contents, and write them to a new file. Test that new file with Ansible. I would even do the same thing, but starting with the YAML file that *doesn't* work. This could potentially help illuminate whether it's something about ruamel.yaml or something about Python itself that's causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for the `dump` method of the `YAML` class is:

```
def dump(
    self: Any, data: Union[Path, StreamType], stream: Any = None, *, transform: Any = None
) -> Any:
   ...
```

so you have to include **where** you want to stream your `db` datastructure to. (The dump method at this moment always returns `None`, so printing that doesn't make much sense).

If you want to dump to stdout use:

```
yaml.dump(db, sys.stdout)
```

If you provide a `pathlib.Path` instance as the second paramater it will be
correctly opened as a stream for dumping:

```
yaml.dump(db, outfile)
```

either of the above should get rid of that exception.

`ruamel.yaml` normally raises a `TypeError('Need a stream argument when not dumping from context manager')` I am not sure why you don't see that, but I think ansible gobbles that up (I made myself a note to check if there is a test for that incorrect usage).

Comment: i edited above for what i am doing - and it is not solving the problem.  The none error you speak of prevents the code from running at all. I get the file. It looks good. ansible barfs.

Comment: Have you tried the full traceback as indicated (`-vvv`)?

Answer (score -1):

So -vvv was the answer. I blame covid (working on this with a fever) the none was some other missing parameter - just wasn't clear without -vvv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).